# Sci-fi movie where people in a submarine see something that starts making their dreams come true

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

All I remember is that it's about some group of people traveling in a submarine in the sea (i think), they see something in the sea and after they're returning home their dreams starting to come true.

I also remember that one of them is reading a book that doesn't have an ending.

Sorry, can't remember anything else.
Very appreciate your help!

Comment: Releasing year? Hollywood or else?

Comment: Sphere is the movie. :)

Answer (score 24):

The plot you've outlined reminds me of [Sphere](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120184/), a 1998 Sci-Fi psychological thriller film adapted from a Michael Chrichton novel — although they don't return "home", they return back to their underwater habitat.

Synopsis:

> In the middle of the southern Pacific Ocean, a thousand feet below the surface, what is believed to be an alien spacecraft is discovered after a ship laying transoceanic cable has its cable cut and the United States Navy investigates the cause. The thickness of coral growth on the spaceship suggests that it has been there for almost 300 years. A team made up of marine biologist Dr. Beth Halperin (Sharon Stone), mathematician Dr. Harry Adams (Samuel L. Jackson), astrophysicist Dr. Ted Fielding (Liev Schreiber), psychologist Dr. Norman Goodman (Dustin Hoffman), and U.S. Navy Capt. Harold Barnes (Peter Coyote) are tasked with investigating the spaceship. The team (along with two navy technicians) are housed in a state-of-the-art underwater living environment called the Habitat during their stay on the ocean floor.

...

> Eventually, only Harry, Norman, and Beth remain. At this point, they realize that they have all entered the world of the perfect sphere. The Sphere has given them the power to manifest their thoughts into reality. As such, all of the disasters that had been plaguing them are the result of manifestations of the worst parts of their own minds.

**EDIT** It's been a while since I saw the film so I didn't want to confirm the last part of your question, as I thought I remembered an unfinished book but was unsure… this [TV Tropes article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlankBook) confirms:

> This happened with Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea in the film version of Sphere. It wasn't completely blank, but just stopped where the reader was too scared to read past that page while he was a child.

Comment: Actually, he was scared of shrimps and squids, from that page he stopped reading.